# Remove extra spaces but not space between two words

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove extra spaces present in my string. I have tried `trim`,`ltrim`,`rtrim` and others but non of them are working and even tried the below stuffs.

```
//This removes all the spaces even the space between the words 
// which i want to be kept
$new_string = preg_replace('/\s/u', '', $old_string);
```

Is there any solution for this ?

Updated:-

Input String:-

```
"
Hello Welcome
                             to India    "
```

Output String:-

```
"Hello Welcome to India"
```

Comment: Can you give your data?

Comment: Give some examples of what you want to accomplish (string you start from, string you want to get)

Comment: trim should do fine. However, if you wanna use regex, can try this `^\s*|\s*$`

Comment: How did you use `trim`? [It should work exactly as you would like it to](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.trim.php) (removing whitespace from the start and end of a string only).

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question. Do you want the string `" a   b  "` to become `"a   b"` or `"a b"`?

Comment: I want it to become "a b"

Comment: does your string also contains html characters, like <br /> etc

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$cleanStr = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $str)));
```

Answer (score 14):

OK, so you want to trim *all*  whitespace from the end of the string and *excess*  whitespace between words.

You can do this with a single regex:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/', '', $subject);
```

**Explanation:**

```
^\s+      # Match whitespace at the start of the string
|         # or
\s+$      # Match whitespace at the end of the string
|         # or
\s+(?=\s) # Match whitespace if followed by another whitespace character
```

Like this (example in Python because I don't use PHP):

```
>>> re.sub(r"^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)", "", "  Hello\n   and  welcome to  India   ")
'Hello and welcome to India'
```

Comment: this does not seem to remove spaces created by &nbsp;

Comment: @DragonFire: If you're applying the regex to the source code, then yes - `&nbsp;` is not whitespace, neither would be `%20` or `0x20` etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove multiple spaces within a string you can use the following:

```
$testStr = "                  Hello Welcome
                         to India    ";
$ro = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $testStr));
```

Comment: OP does not want to remove spaces anywhere except the start/end of the string.

Comment: OP wants to remove extra spaces in the middle of the string.

Comment: My updated script returns "Hello Welcome to India" as required.

Answer (score 3):

I Think what we are supposed to do here is we should not look for 1 space we should look for consecutive two spaces and then make it one. So this way it would not replace the space between the text and also remove any other space.

> `$new_string= str_replace('  ', ' ', $old_string)`

for more on [Str Replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

If You remove single space between word. try it

`trim(str_replace(' ','','hello word'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will also remove all &nbsp

```
$node3 = htmlentities($node3, null, 'utf-8');
$node3 = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $node3);
$node3 = html_entity_decode($node3);

$node3 = preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/', '', $node3);
```