# trim white space from sides and allow spaces between words

Tags: php, preg-match, whitespace

I was trying to trim white spaces from all sides but allow the single spaces between the words typed?

I am using the following code:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/',$_POST['username'])){
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $_SESSION['notmet'] = "Invalid username. You can only use letters and/or digits";
            header('location: index.php');}}
```

What am I exactly getting wrong here?

Comment: Where is the code that is supposed to *trim white spaces from all sides but allow the single spaces between the words*? BTW, it is `trim()` that does it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm just guessing but maybe they want to trim excessive whitespaces in between words?

Comment: Anyway, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570744/remove-extra-spaces-but-not-space-between-two-words would do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I figured there was a dupe for this question regardless of OP's vagueness.

Comment: Yeah, unless OP asks about something totally different than it is written in the question.

Comment: I am using preg match, the user solutions are using preg replace, so I was confused and reached for help.