# Is there validation/function to trim whitespace in sentences between words in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Is there validation to trim whitespace in sentences between words?

for example,

there is a field name, and user input the value like this :

`"     jhon     doe               cool     "`

so, how to trim it so that when it stored to the database it will look like this :

`"jhon doe cool"`

I know `trim()` function and I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386203/laravel-5-validation-trim) and [this](http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-middleware-to-remove-trim-empty-whitespace-from-the-input-request),
But it only works for whitespaces at the beginning and end, not for whitespace between the words

I use this in my controller for validation and input to the database

```php
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|max:50',
    'srn' => 'required|size:9',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'major' => 'required',
]);
Student::create($request->all());
return redirect('/students')->with('status', 'Data successfully added!');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove extra spaces but not space between two words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570744/remove-extra-spaces-but-not-space-between-two-words)

Comment: Have you read the question? it's about removing the extra spaces that *should* be removed except for 1 space between words, so yes it is a duplicate

Comment: Removing space is different from validating something, can you make it clear?

Comment: @CaddyDZ I just want to ask if there is instantly way to use the features available in Laravel, instead of writing regex manually, But it has been answered below, if laravel uses regex validator, But if there is a more instant way, it will really help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out and surfing again the internet,

I followed the way like the link i [mentioned](http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-middleware-to-remove-trim-empty-whitespace-from-the-input-request) above, but I added a few lines of code and used `preg_replace` and `str_replace` as trim delimeters,

use the PHP artisan command to create the middleware file to trim request data,

`php artisan make:middleware BeforeAutoTrimmer`

and edit the function, place `array_walk_recursive` inside if statement, and invoke trim function following with `preg_replace` and `str_replace` , the pattern look likes @kyle answer

```
if ($input) {
    array_walk_recursive($input, function (&$item) {
        $item = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $item)));
        $item = ($item == "") ? null : $item;
    });

      $request->merge($input);
 }
```

and the class with trim method will look like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class BeforeAutoTrimmer
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        if ($input) {
            array_walk_recursive($input, function (&$item) {
                $item = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $item)));
                $item = ($item == "") ? null : $item;
            });

           $request->merge($input);
        }
      return $next($request);
    }
}
```

it will automatically remove the extra whitespace every input to database

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 10.x

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$string = Str::of('    laravel    framework    ')->squish();
```

Documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/strings#method-str-squish

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a regular expression validator.

> Internally, this rule uses the PHP preg_match function. The pattern specified should obey the same formatting required by preg_match and thus also include valid delimiters. For example: 'email' => 'regex:/^.+@.+$/i'.
>
> Note: When using the regex / not_regex patterns, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-regex

So:

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => [
       'required',
       'max: 50',
       'regex:/\s+/'
    ]
]);
```

's' matches any whitespace, '+' means unlimited times.

Good tool for testing regex: https://regex101.com/

P.s I haven't tested this will give you the correct output but should put you on the right path

Comment: can i use with other validation rule? i've been tried like this and not working `'name' => 'required|max:50|regex:/\s+/'`

Comment: still not working, the extra whitespace still involved to database :(